# Add a total quantity column for groups of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate, window-functions

I have an Items table and an Inventory table.  An Item can belong to multiple Inventory records.  I'm trying to return a list of ALL Inventory records but with their quantity in a new column.  For instance:

**Items**

```
ItemID     ItemDescription
103        Headphones
115        Speakers
230        Wireless Adapter
275        20' Network Cable
```

**Inventory**

```
InventoryID        ItemID        WarrantyDate       Status
1                  103           12/22/2010         Available
2                  103           05/15/2012         Available
3                  103           02/24/2015
4                  275           01/01/2010
5                  275           01/01/2011
```

If I try to `COUNT` the ItemID and `GROUP BY` ItemID, like so:

```
SELECT ItemID, COUNT(ItemID) AS Quantity
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY ItemID
```

I get:

```
ItemID  Quantity
103     3
275     2
```

But what I really want is this:

```
InventoryID        ItemID        WarrantyDate       Status       Quantity
1                  103           12/22/2010         Available    3
2                  103           05/15/2012         Available    3
3                  103           02/24/2015                      3
4                  275           01/01/2010                      2
5                  275           01/01/2011                      2
```

Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `OVER` clause on the `COUNT` function to get what you need:

```
CREATE TABLE #inventory(
   InventoryID  INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,ItemID       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,WarrantyDate DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Status       VARCHAR(9)
);
INSERT INTO #inventory(InventoryID,ItemID,WarrantyDate,Status) VALUES (1,103,'12/22/2010','Available');
INSERT INTO #inventory(InventoryID,ItemID,WarrantyDate,Status) VALUES (2,103,'05/15/2012','Available');
INSERT INTO #inventory(InventoryID,ItemID,WarrantyDate,Status) VALUES (3,103,'02/24/2015',NULL);
INSERT INTO #inventory(InventoryID,ItemID,WarrantyDate,Status) VALUES (4,275,'01/01/2010',NULL);
INSERT INTO #inventory(InventoryID,ItemID,WarrantyDate,Status) VALUES (5,275,'01/01/2011',NULL);

SELECT *, COUNT(ItemID) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID) AS Quantity
FROM #Inventory
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| InventoryID | ItemID | WarrantyDate |  Status   | Quantity |
+-------------+--------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|           1 |    103 | 2010-12-22   | Available |        3 |
|           2 |    103 | 2012-05-15   | Available |        3 |
|           3 |    103 | 2015-02-24   | NULL      |        3 |
|           4 |    275 | 2010-01-01   | NULL      |        2 |
|           5 |    275 | 2011-01-01   | NULL      |        2 |
+-------------+--------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this., it works as expected now....I tried using the `OVER PARTITION BY` but I think I had the wrong syntax or columns because it didn't work before.